# Is it possible to require images with a dynamic string and without using Xcode?

Tags: react-native

**This code works:**

```
<Image source={require('./../img/icons/mlb/kc.png')} />
```

**This code does not:**

```
var team = 'kc'; //Retrieved from API
var string = './../img/icons/mlb/'+team+'.png'
<Image source={require(string)} />
```

**Error:**

> Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module
>   "./../img/icons/mlb/kc.png".If you are sure the module is there, try
>   restarting the packager or running "npm install".

Is there any way to include images dynamically without adding them to Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to React's [Image documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html), no, it is not possible.

> Note that in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

You could do that if you knew all of the images in advance and require them beforehand. Then, you could use the team name directly as the image name.

Something like this:

```
var teamA = require("./../img/icons/mlb/teamA.png");
var teamB = require("./../img/icons/mlb/teamB.png");
var teamC = require("./../img/icons/mlb/teamC.png");

// if you like imports better, then:
// import { default as teamA } from "./img/icons/mlb/teamA.png";
// import { default as teamB } from "./img/icons/mlb/teamB.png";
// import { default as teamC } from "./img/icons/mlb/teamC.png";

const teamByName = (teamName) => {
    switch (teamName) {
        case "teamA": return teamA;
        case "teamB": return teamB;
        case "teamC": return teamC;
    }
};

const TeamImage = ({team}) => (
    <Image source={teamByName(team)} />
);
```

**Edit:**

By the way, you don't have to add images through Xcode. You can just place them inside your app folders, like you do with your components. I like to keep mine like this:

```
ROOT
| index.ios.js
| - app
|   |- (other javascript files)
| - img
|   |- (image files like png, jpg, gif)
```